# How can I use QML Layouts to Size Nested Layouts in ScrollView?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

I am trying to use QML layouts to size sections of a UI within a `ScrollView` and having trouble understanding why one of the nested `GridLayouts` is being clipped.  To understand it better, please see the picture below and look specifically at the bottom of "Section 1":

[image: Layout Confusion]

I think, basically, the issue is that "Section 2" implicit height(the smaller of the two side-by-side sections) is driving the sizing for that row in the magenta GridLayout instead of the other way around, as I would hope.  I'm trying to get the code down to something allowed in the length of the question and will edit as soon as I do.

Comment: Hi, did you size items inside a `GridLayout` using `preferredWidth`?

Comment: @SMR, I did indeed.  All of the field labels and "control" fields are sized with a `preferredWidth`.  I tried `preferredHeight` values for all as well, but with a similar result. I don't understand why the vertically smaller of the two nested `GridLayouts` (Section 2) would be the "driver" for the height of the outer `GridLayout`.

Comment: If it's possible, please modify your question and give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since I tried what you mentioned and there was absolutely no clipping.

Comment: I ended up "solving" the problem by adding a test before setting the `preferredHeight` on the `Rectangle`s that comprise each of the "Sections".  I guess I thought the `Layouts` would resize with different "logic".  I'll post an answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the sizing issue with a test for which "Section" `Rectangle` was vertically larger (`implicitHeight`) before setting the `Layout.preferredHeight` for both of the "Sections".

```
Rectangle { //Section 1 rectangle
               color: "black"
               clip: true

               Layout.fillHeight: true
               Layout.fillWidth: true
               Layout.preferredWidth: widthMainControlCommon
               Layout.preferredHeight: { layoutSec1.implicitHeight > layoutSec2.implicitHeight ?
                    layoutSec1.implicitHeight : layoutSec2.implicitHeight}

               GridLayout {
                    id: layoutSec1
                    columns: 2
                    anchors.fill: parent
               }
//..

    Rectangle { //Section 2 rectangle
               color: "black"
               clip: true

               Layout.fillHeight: true
               Layout.fillWidth: true
               Layout.preferredWidth: widthMainControlCommon
               Layout.preferredHeight: { layoutSec1.implicitHeight > layoutSec2.implicitHeight ?
                    layoutSec1.implicitHeight : layoutSec2.implicitHeight}

               GridLayout {
                    id: layoutSec2
                    columns: 2
                    anchors.fill: parent
               }
```

I don't understand the benefits of the `Layouts` like I thought I did, or the logic that drives sizing when they're nested.  Needing to set a `preferredHeight` in order to get the `Layout` to size to make it visible seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ScrollView`. I highly recommend you look at components that have a `ScrollBar` property first such as `Flickable` and `ListView`.

To demonstrate, I mocked up the following example demonstrating how you can use `ListView` with the `ScrollBar.vertical` property set to recreate the UI/UX shown in your question.

For the `delegate` I use a `DelegateChooser` so each row can have a different delegate. For the `model` I use a `ListModel` which is used to populate the different input types.

For each delegate, I add the following code to ensure that when that control is being edited, its focus is forced to be visible. i.e. it avoids the control being clipped.

```
    onActiveFocusChanged: listView.currentIndex = index
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    Frame {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "black"
            border.color: "#f0f"
            border.width: 2
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            RowLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                SectionInput {
                    title: "SECTION 1"
                    model: Data1 { }
                }
                SectionInput {
                    title: "SECTION 2"
                    model: Data2 { }
                }
            }
            SectionInput {
                title: "SECTION 3"
                model: Data3 { }
            }
        }
    }
}

// SectionInput.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels

Frame {
    id: sectionInput
    property string title
    property ListModel model
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "black"
        border.color: "yellow"
        border.width: 2
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        Text {
            text: title
            color: "cyan"
        }
        
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: sectionInput.model
            clip: true
            spacing: 10
            snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                width: 20
                policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            }
            delegate: DelegateChooser {
                id: chooser
                role: "typ"
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "combo"; MyCombo { } }
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "text"; MyText { } }
                DelegateChoice { roleValue: "switch"; MySwitch { } }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MyCombo.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

RowLayout {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width - 20
    Text {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        text: lab
        color: "white"
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }
    ComboBox {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        model: dat.split(",")
        onAccepted: val = currentText
        onActiveFocusChanged: listView.currentIndex = index
        Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = find(val)
    }
}

// MyText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

RowLayout {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width - 20
    Text {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        text: lab
        color: "white"
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }
    TextField {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        background: Rectangle { color: "#ddd" }
        text: val
        placeholderText: pla
        onAccepted: val = text
        onActiveFocusChanged: listView.currentIndex = index
    }
}

// MySwitch.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

RowLayout {
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width - 20
    Text {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        text: lab
        color: "white"
        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignRight
    }
    Frame {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 100
        background: Item { }
        Switch {
            checked: val === "true"
            onToggled: val = JSON.stringify(checked)
            onActiveFocusChanged: listView.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
}

// Data1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ListModel {
    ListElement { lab: "Field 1"; typ: "combo"; val: "F1"; dat: "F0,F1,F2,F3" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 2"; typ: "text"; pla: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 3"; typ: "text"; pla: "xx,xxx" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 4"; typ: "text"; pla: "x,xxx" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 5"; typ: "text"; pla: "xxx"  }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 6"; typ: "text"; pla: "xx" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 7"; typ: "text" }
}

// Data2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ListModel {
    ListElement { lab: "Field 1"; typ: "combo"; val: "TTL"; dat: "TTL,XYZ,ABC" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 2"; typ: "combo"; val: "50"; dat: "5,50,500" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 3"; typ: "combo"; val: "50"; dat: "40,50,60" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 4"; typ: "combo"; val: "Normal"; dat: "Normal,Not Normal" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 5"; typ: "combo"; val: "Normal"; dat: "Normal,Not Normal" }
}

// Data3.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ListModel {
    ListElement { lab: "Field 1"; typ: "switch"; val: "true" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 2"; typ: "combo"; val: "OFF"; dat: "ON,OFF" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 3"; typ: "switch"; val: "false" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 4"; typ: "text" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 5"; typ: "text" }
    ListElement { lab: "Field 6"; typ: "text" }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: So where are the `ScrollView` and `RowLayout`? No `ListView` is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SMR thanks for your feedback. You are correct. There was no mention of `ScrollView` in my answer and there is no mention of `ListView` in the question. I do mention `ListView` because, sometimes, it may be a better fit for implementing scrolling in programs, so, I felt it was worthy of offering the approach for consideration. In anything, I was hoping it solicit any response, positive or negative which, I will adapt the answer accordingly. The question kind of demands more information to be answered more thoroughly anyways, so, my answer was merely a mechanism to stimulate more information.

Comment: Would be helpful to explain the drawback of using ScrollView.

Comment: @jwalk ScrollView is ScrollView, nothing more. Whereas those other components have implicit scrolling with some other capability included. i.e. why go for a low-level component when you can go for a more comprehensive component. Less is more right? That's what we want from a declarative language like QML.